# View visible again after activity is minimized and then restored

Tags: java, android, lottie

I've been getting this weird thing in my app.

I have an `AppCompatActivity`, which has `ViewPager` inside it, which contains two fragments. I've added `LottieAnimationView` inside both the fragments.

In `FragmentA` I'm fetching data from server using `Retrofit`, and on loading, it hides the `LottieAnimationView`. In `FragmentB`(which is only for purpose of checking what's wrong), I'm just using `Handler` to hide the `LottieAnimationView` after 3 seconds.

Now, whenever I minimize the app, and then open it again, I see the `LottieAnimationView` that I `setVisibility(View.GONE)` only in `FragmentA`. In `FragmentB`, I do not see the View when I `setVisibility(View.GONE)` after minimizing and opening app again (which works as expected).

Here's the image of what I see in `FragmentA`.

[image]

The `LottieAnimationView` is in paused state.

Here's the code to my `FragmentA`.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private AdapterEventStore mAdapter;
    private List<Item> mStore;
    private final String hostName = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx";
    private View view;
    private Context context;
    private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        context = view.getContext();
        lottieAnimationView = view.findViewById(R.id.ais_lav_loading);
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        initRecyclerView();
        return view;
    }


    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView store = view.findViewById(R.id.ais_rv_event_store);
        store.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mStore = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new AdapterEventStore(context, mStore);
        store.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        fetchDataFromServer();
    }

    private void fetchDataFromServer() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(hostName)
                .build();
        APIGetItem itemShop = retrofit.create(APIGetItem.class);

        Call<ModelEventExclusive> call = itemShop.getEventStore(hostName);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelEventExclusive>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelEventExclusive> call, Response<ModelEventExclusive> response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response.body().getItems().get(0).getItemName());
                mEventStore.addAll(response.body().getItems());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideLottieAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelEventExclusive> call, Throwable t) {
                hideLottieAnimation();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error:"+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error occurred: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void hideLottieAnimation(){
        lottieAnimationView.cancelAnimation();
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Layout for `FragmentA`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ais_rv_event_store"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/ais_lav_loading"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:lottie_repeatMode="reverse"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/loading" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Please note that the Visibility of `LottieAnimationView` is set to `GONE` at first.
The above code to fetch items 100% works, please don't point out any errors in syntax/variable names as I've done bad job at trying to hide the actual variable/class names.

Here's the code to `FragmentB`

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private LottieAnimationView anim_loading;
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        anim_loading = view.findViewById(R.id.lav_loading);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                anim_loading.cancelAnimation();
                anim_loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 3000);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Can you please tell what I'm doing wrong here? Why it works as expected in one fragment and doesn't in another? Does it have to do anything with how I'm hiding it inside Retrofit callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you get form the background, the `onResume` gets called, so you need to add the line to hide the view in `onResume`, not `onCreateView`.

Check out the [Android Developer page on fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line from onCrete and add put it inside the fetchDataFromServer() method like this..

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private AdapterEventStore mAdapter;
    private List<Item> mStore;
    private final String hostName = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx";
    private View view;
    private Context context;
    private LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        context = view.getContext();
        lottieAnimationView = view.findViewById(R.id.ais_lav_loading);
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        initRecyclerView();
        return view;
    }


    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView store = view.findViewById(R.id.ais_rv_event_store);
        store.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        mStore = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new AdapterEventStore(context, mStore);
        store.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        fetchDataFromServer();
    }

    private void fetchDataFromServer() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(hostName)
                .build();
        APIGetItem itemShop = retrofit.create(APIGetItem.class);



        Call<ModelEventExclusive> call = itemShop.getEventStore(hostName);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelEventExclusive>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelEventExclusive> call, Response<ModelEventExclusive> response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response.body().getItems().get(0).getItemName());
                mEventStore.addAll(response.body().getItems());
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideLottieAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelEventExclusive> call, Throwable t) {
                hideLottieAnimation();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error:"+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error occurred: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void hideLottieAnimation(){
        lottieAnimationView.cancelAnimation();
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: The LottieAnimationView is hidden initially. So I'm making it VISIBLE at launch.

Comment: please clear me one thing.. when to show when to hide?

Comment: It's shown at the start, when the fetching of items from server starts. And then I hide it once the data is fetched from the server.

Comment: you can try the above code..it will do so.. if you turn visibility on in oncreate it will always show after maximize. in that case you can use onresume overide method to hide it

Comment: Change your answer and add the onResume thing. I didn't add the code to hide it inside onResume. What you said about onCreateView is wrong. Now that I added code to hide it in onResume, it works as expected.

Comment: i have edited the answer.. I think i expect an appreciation and upvote.. thank you dude